# Can color of data label be different inside and outside of the bar in Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm wondering that the color of the text which is inside the bar chart(plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.color) can be different if the text doesn't fit to bar length. For instance: 
[image]

Code is here:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 700
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0.2,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'black',
                align: "right",
                format: '{y} M',
                inside: false,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                verticalAlign: "middle"
            },
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 2.33]
    }]
});
```

});

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Possible solution is to use formatter. Determine if value is lower than some level, and then change dataLabel color. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/176/

```
                formatter: function() {
                    var max = this.series.yAxis.max,
                        color =  this.y / max < 0.05 ? 'black' : 'white'; // 5% width
                    return '<span style="color: ' + color + '">' + this.y + ' M</span>';   
                },
```

You can also compare point's width with length of y-value string.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have a column chart, and by default I want my labels to be white color and rotated to -90 degrees. But if the column size is small, the rotation should be zero and black color;
How can I make the rotation optional?

Comment: Try to use formatter still: use some CSS rotations, instead of Highcharts built-in one. Or add resize event for document in which you will update series with new rotation, when required.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the color to `contrast`, and it will change depending on whether the dataLabel is inside/outside the bar.

```
style: {
    color: 'contrast'
}
```

Comment: I'm just getting black labels regardless of where the bar is. Any working examples?

Answer (score 3):

I use the "isInside" value like so:

```js
 series: [{
   name: 'Percentage',
   data: this.calculateChartSeries(),
   dataLabels: {
     enabled: true,
     rotation: 0,
     align: 'right',
     borderWidth: 1,
     formatter: function() {
       if (this.point.isInside == true) {
         return '<span style="color: white">' + this.y + '%</span>';
       } else {
         return '<span style="color: black">' + this.y + '%</span>';
       }
     }
   }
 }]
```

But if that doesn't work for you, it's possible to use "this.point.shapeArgs.height"  and check if that height is greater than the length of your text.

Comment: The `isInside`property refers to whether the data point is inside the *plot area*, not whether the label has been placed inside a bar or column as shown in the original poster's screenshot.

Comment: upvote for the idea with the property `this.point.shapeArgs.height`