# Can color of data label be different inside and outside of the bar in Highchart, even if it has negative numbers?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having the same issue of the post below: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011614/can-color-of-data-label-be-different-inside-and-outside-of-the-bar-in-highchart/24013063)

However the problem happen when the data contain negative values:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 700
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0.2,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: "right",                    
                inside: false,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                formatter: function() {
                    var max = this.series.yAxis.max,
                        color =  this.y / max < 0.05 ? 'black' : 'white'; // 5% width
                    return '<span style="color: ' + color + '">' + this.y + ' M</span>';   
                },
                verticalAlign: "middle"
            },
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [-29.9, -71.5, -106.4, -129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 2.33]
    }]
});

});
```

How do I fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify @Paweł Fus' solution to accommodate negative numbers like so:

```
formatter: function() {
    var min = Math.abs(this.series.yAxis.min) //Since min can be negative
    var max = Math.abs(this.series.yAxis.max) //Since max can be negative
    var pt = Math.abs(this.y)
    var highest = Math.max(min,max)
    var color =  pt / highest < 0.05 ? 'black' : 'white'; // 5% width
            return '<span style="color: ' + color + '">' + this.y + ' M</span>'
},
```

Using the **`highest`** variable (*which contains the largest length on either side of the x-axis*). You essentially want the distance from *`origin`*. To figure out if the data-label is inside or outside.

The `Math.abs` help resolve that!